# jquery-ui-rails not showing list of suggestions

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Hello I have followed the autocomplete revised railscast youtube video but I don't know why it's missing.

This is my application.js:

```js
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

This my products.js.coffee:

```js
jQuery ->
$("#search_term").autocomplete
source: ["foo", "food", "four"]
```

And this my application.html.erb(the searchbox part):

```html
<% if controller.controller_name == 'products' %>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search_term" id="search_term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

The thing is that I have tried to paste the above code from the application.html.erb file in the product.index.html to see if by doing that will have an effect on it (because the jquery code is in the product.js.coffee) but it didn't work either.

Comment: Do you need to indent your coffee script or is that a typo?

Comment: This is what it shows on the video. Maybe there's another way...

Comment: Blocks are defined with indentation in CoffeeScript so try indenting each line on the products.js.coffee code

Comment: Nops, it doesn't work despite the indentation